# Typescript eslint getting wird errors

Tags: typescript

`010

1. *List item*

`ESlint errors on typescript

[image]

`data` it's not any

[image]

Don't know why eslint keep failing on this

```
type AuthenticateWithFingerprintCallParameters = {
    visitorId: string;
    userClaims: Record<string, string>;
  };
```

That's how I'm calling the funciton

```
sendFetchAuthenticateWithFingerpint({ visitorId, userClaims })
```

Comment: There's a chance it's an IDE issue, you could try restarting it

Comment: Not seeing any reason to check the _truthiness_ of `data` since it's not marked optional / nullable

Comment: Exactly, I was testing to understand why it's complains on visitorId